# session variable mixup in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, session, variables

Is it possible for ASP.NET to mix up which user is associated with which session variable on the server? Are session variables immutably tied to the original user that created them across time, space & dimension?

Comment: I have a session where they are, in fact, getting mixed up.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646274/asp-net-session-mix-up-using-stateserver-scary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your original question: Sessions are keyed to an id that is placed in a cookie.  This id is generated using some random number crypto routines.  It is not guaranteed to be unique but it is highly unlikely that it will ever be duplicated in the span of the life of a session.  Even if your sessions run for full work days.  It would probably take years for a really popular site to even generate a duplicate key (No stats or facts to back that up).

Having said all that it doesn't appear that your problem is with session values getting mixed up.  The first thing that I would start to look at is connection pooling.  ADO pools connections by default but if you request a connection with a username/password that is not in the pool it should give you a new connection.  Hint that may be a performance bottleneck in the future if your site is very large.  It has been a while since I worked with SQL Server, in Oracle there is a call that can be made to switch the identity of the user.  I would be surprised if there was no equivalent in SQL Server.  You might try connecting to your DB with a generic username/password and then executing that identity switch call before you hand back the connection to the rest of your code.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your session provider, if you have overriden the session key generation in a way that is no longer unique, then multiple users may be accessing the same session.

What behavior are you seeing?  And are you sure there's no static in play with the variables you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

while anything is possible. . . .

No, unless you are storing session state in sql server or some other out of process storage and then messing with it. . .

Answer (score 0):

The session is bound to a user cookie, the chances of that messing up in a normal scenario is very unlikely, however there could be issues if using distributed session state.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Sessions are tied to the creator.

Do you want to mix up, or do you have a case when it looks like mixed up?

Answer (score 0):

More information:

I've got an app that takes the userid/password from the login page and stores it in a session variable. I plop it into my connection string for making calls to SQL Server.

When a table gets updated, we're using 'system_user' in the database to identify the 'last updated by' user. We're seeing some odd behavior in which the user we're expecting to be listed is incorrect, and it's showing someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Can you pop in the debugger and see if the correct value is indeed being passed on that connection string?  It would quickly help you idenfity which side the problem is on.

Also make sure that none of the connection code has static properties for connection or user, or one user may have their connection replaced with that of the most recent user before the update fires off.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're re-using a static field on a class to hold the connection string.  Those static fields are re-used across multiple IIS requests so you're probably only ever seeing the most recently logged in user in the 'last updated by'.

BTW, unless you have a REALLY good reason for doing so then you shouldn't be connecting to the DB like this.  You're preventing yourself from using connection pooling which is going to hurt performance under high loads.