# seesion value conflict on server not in localhost in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

i have a login page where i retrieve the name of employee from database as

```
Session["Emp_Name"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Emp_Mas_Name"].ToString()
```

after that i assign it to a string variable in my master page as

```
string Emp_Name = Session["Emp_Name"].ToString();
```

and i use that variable in aspx page to display the name as

```
<%=Emp_Name%>
```

it works fine in localhost but when it's on a live server it sometimes it shows another employee name who logged in at the same time in different systems.

please guide me to resolve this problem, thank you very much

Comment: Classic problem of using Session in web farms.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574388/asp-net-sessions-getting-crossed-mixed-up

Comment: thankyou for the same, let me try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session in asp.net is a classic problem,  but in your case i assume that it is not the actual problem.

This problem may occurs due to

- You have declared the string variable globally
- You have declared the `string Emp_Name` as static

Comment: you are right i have declared the variable as static. Thank you