# Negative Impact of Turning Off Kernel Caching?

Tags: asp.net, iis, session-cookies

In effort to prevent session swapping, we are thinking of turning off Kernel Caching in our ASP.NET web forms app. I've been reading all about this, like [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2017/01/19/asp-net-session-swapping-why-it-happens-and-what-can-be-done-about-it/), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574388/asp-net-sessions-getting-crossed-mixed-up).

But what I'm not seeing anything about is what kind of user-experience impact this may have.  Should we expect page load times to increase?