# Session Swapping after Checkpoint Firewall implemenation

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x, checkpoint

Every thing was working fine until we have configured checkpoint.
For checkpoint, we have a separate vpc in aws.

After that this bug started randomly. Some users are switched with other user. Example let's say User A was logged into application and after some time User A was suddenly changed with User B. This is so random that i am not able to find the way to reproduce. But end users are reporting it periodically.

My application is built in Yii 1 and logic mechanics is straight forward. Session is setting when user logged into website.

## Yii1 Configuration

```
<?php
return array(
    'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..',
    'name' => 'Project',
    'defaultController' => 'site/login',
    // application components
    'components' => array(
        'request' => array(
            'enableCsrfValidation' => true,
            'enableCookieValidation' => true,
            'class' => 'HttpRequest',
            'csrfTokenName' => '_csrf',
        ),
        'session' => array(
            'class' => 'CDbHttpSession',
            'autoStart' => true,
            'connectionID' => 'db',
            'sessionTableName' => 'tbl_session',
            'timeout' => 3600 * 24 * 30,
            'autoCreateSessionTable' => false
        ),
        'user' => array(
            'allowAutoLogin' => true,
            'authTimeout' => 3600 * 24 * 30,
        ),
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        //Other Stuff
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ),
);
```

Below is the sample request:

**Note: i have changed the URLs to dummy one.**

## General

Request URL: https://[randomuniquestring].access.project.com/index.php?r=home/index
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200
Remote Address: 143.204.*****:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

## Request Headers

:authority: randomuniquestring.access.project.com
:method: GET
:path: /index.php?r=home/index
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: max-age=0
cookie: selected_realm=ssl_vpn; _gcl_au=1.1.997081439.1542180219;   __qca=P0-2107182343-1542180221727; _ga=GA1.2.663976907.1542956670;   ___fnbDropDownState=1; CPCVPN_BASE_HOST=.access.project.com;   CPCVPN_OBSCURE_KEY=6a97dc429cb24dafe51d5177d2e87218;     _gid=GA1.2.33488363.1549271004;   CPCVPN_SESSION_ID=96c6835fb518aeefe7eb64e5767c730401e4f547; _gat=1;   CPCVPN_SDATA_VERSION=2
referer: https://[randomuniquestring].access.project.com/index.php?
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36

## Response Header

cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
content-length: 0
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Thu, 07 Feb 2019 10:38:55 GMT
expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
location: https://[randomuniquestring].access.project.com/?r=home/index
pragma: no-cache
server: CPWS
set-cookie: CPCVPN_SDATA_VERSION=2; path=/; secure; HttpOnly;
status: 302
strict-transport-security: max-age=1261440000; includeSubDomains
vary: User-Agent
via: 1.1 [randomuniquestring].cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: lWZ0rvOKiPO5FhJk6oPqdTchfzzsrTlb6du1DD6rNaOQZDSL1cGlcw==
x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN

I have refer this question: [PHP cookie-bases session swapping in phorum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50218639/php-cookie-bases-session-swapping-in-phorum) but didn't found any solution.

So is there a way to find the root cause behind it and how to resolve this one?

## Other Detail

For a checkpoint, we have a separate vpc in aws.
This vpc contains link and other migrated application

Comment: Your session component configuration may be relevant here.

Comment: @rob006 added the session configuration.

Comment: @DS9 +1..?? I did it :P

Comment: @VidhyutPandya (lol)